# Reload vim autocmd Filetype

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

I tried searching for this on the internet but I get bombarded with answers saying to `:so $MYVIMRC`which does not work if I add lines of the type `autocmd FileType foo bar`.

What's a more efficient way to apply the effects instead of opening `.vimrc`, closing vim and then opening the file I was editing again?

Answer (score 0):

`FileType` autocommands are triggered when the `filetype` option is **set**. Hence to reload an `autocmd` you added/edited, after `:so $MYVIMRC`, you should do something like

```
:set ft=<your filetype>
```

on the target file.
As a mapping to do that automatically :

```
noremap <leader>rft :exe ':set filetype='.&filetype<CR>
```

Comment: Or `:w | e` (edit triggers the events too)